# How to display an Image to component?

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, bufferedimage

How to display an image to `JPanel` or to `JLabel` using the `BufferedImage`? 
I load an Image using `FileChooser` and I need to display what I've loaded.
I don't extend my class to any container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override <del>paintComponents(g)</del> `paintComponent(g)` method of JPanel or JLabel and draw image in it. Something like follow:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            BufferedImage image = null; // get your buffered image.
            Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            graphics2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            super.paintComponents(g);
        }
    };
```

Same thing for JLabel. Or in another way:

```
    BufferedImage image = null; // get your buffered image.
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon((Image)image);
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setIcon(icon);
```

As you are saying that you are loading image from `FileChooser` it can be done in following 
way:

```
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(
              fileChooser.getCurrentDirectory().toString()
              +"/"+fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
```

Now you can use ImageIcon in JLabel or add it in JPanel.

---

Above code is sample code and not tested so not necessary to run without error. You might need to change it as per your need.

Comment: @mre: No. I mean `paintComponents`. I'm not sure `paintComponent` will give same effect or not.

Comment: +1 for two approaches; but @mre is correct, you should override `paintComponent()` and invoke [`super.paintComponent()`](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html).

Comment: @mre: Updated answer as per your suggestions. Thanks for updating my mistake. Also thanks to trahsgod and kleopatra.